# How do I "teleport" an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm trying to make a script where once a player triggers a collision they are teleported to another position that is determined by a empty game object. I think it has to do something with the transform function but I haven't been able to figure it out.

There isn't a good example of this type of behavior in c#. Most examples are written in java and that confuses me even more lol.

Here's what I got so far that works

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class  colision: MonoBehaviour {
    public Object WarpExit;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {Debug.Log("ENTERED WARP ZONE");}

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("IN WARP ZONE");
        //Warp player

    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {Debug.Log("EXITED WARP ZONE");}
}
```

Comment: Just get the `Vector3`, `position` from the empty `GameObject.transform` and set it on your player object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference the exit object, and update your player position to the position of the object.

To reference the exit object, you can either define it in the Inspector after declaring a public property:

```
//Change public Object WarpExit; to:
public GameObject WarpExit;
```

This will then show up in the Inspector as a field where you can select the exit object. This is the most ideal solution if your exit is static and predefined.

Or, you can find the exit object in your script start up, with a tag, object name or if has some kind of "exit script":

```
public void Start() {
    //Choose one method

    //With a tag
    //Requires you to add a tag to your exit object, you can add a tag in the Inspector
    WarpExit = GameObject.FindWithTag("WarpExit"); 

    //or by name
    //Requires you to name your object 'WarpExit', you can change the name in the Inspector
    WarpExit = GameObject.Find("WarpExit");

    //or a component (script)
    //Requires you to create a new script with a class name of 'WarpExitScript' and attaching it to your exit object
    WarpExit = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<WarpExitScript>().gameObject; 
}
```

Once you have your exit object defined, you know it's location, and can use that when "teleporting" your player:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("IN WARP ZONE");
    other.gameObject.transform.position = WarpExit.transform.position;
}
```

As an aside, I'd suggest renaming your script to something like `WarpEntrance` instead of `colision`, as it's a good idea to name your classes based on their functionality.

Comment: Im getting a compiler error for "WarpExit.transform.position;" does not contain a definition for transform

Comment: If you're not defining `WarpExit` as a `GameObject` you'll get that. You might want to check out some basic debugging/troubleshooting steps to help you. The problem you're facing now is one you'll get a lot, and learning how to solve those types of problems yourself will be extremely helpful to you.

Comment: I Forgot to make Warpexit a gameobject instead of a object sorry